# what is the translation for the word "intersection"? when used as an *operation* between volumes or lines. (not a road intersection)

Tags: translation, multiple-readings

intersection when used as an *operation* or *volumetric operation* between volumes or lines.

(not as a road intersection).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tomas, unfortunately we do not do translation requests on this site, whether it be a word translation in context or anything else. If you'd like to ask this type of question, please show whatever partial work you've done already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the set theory operation, there are a few terms as given in [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%B1%E9%80%9A%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86_(%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6)), including:

- 共通部分｛きょうつうぶぶん｝
- 共通集合｛きょうつうしゅうごう｝
- 交差｛こうさ｝
- 交わり｛まじわり｝
- 積集合｛せきしゅうごう｝
- 積｛せき｝

Although the article points out that 積 is also used to refer to the product of two sets, so 共通部分 is probably the preferred term. 共通 is also used for "in common" in other mathematical terms, e.g. if two triangles have the same height they might be referred to as 高さが共通.

As you can see in [this](https://methodology.site/intersection-of-cylinders/) page, the intersection of two or more 3D solids is referred to as 共通｛きょうつう｝部分｛ぶぶん｝の体積｛たいせき｝, and you would have similar terms for intersections of areas and other mathematical constructs.